# Can you guess the phrase?

Tags: rebus

[image]

What is the phrase shown here?
Please ignore the background.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a

> fine line

as the rebus shows

> F in E and L in E

Comment: More directly, it could also be an urgent invitation to FL**EE** :-)

Comment: @Bass - Ecstatic state (7)